# How to save page state in ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

[image: This is first screen where i select buttons]

[image: This sec screen when i click it navigate back to first screen of buttons][image: This is first screen after navigation<code>**</code>enter code here<code>**</code>]

i want to save page state that when user select buttons and after it navigate from sec screen the page must show him selected seats.
for routing i am using angular router.

Comment: Why not save the seat ids in an array and store the array in the local Storgae or data service. And when you navigate back to booking page, get the data and update the layout.

Answer (score -1):

you can send selected seats as URL Query parameters while routing.